# How does cucumber When/Then arguments has the same object_id?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

Just realized if I call twice

```
#test.feature

When test abc cba
and test abc cba

#test_steps.rb

When(/^Test (.+)$/ do |arg|
  puts arg
  arg.remove! 'cba'
end
```

It will first return (`puts`)

`#=> abc cba`

and in the second call

`#=> abc`

...interesting. To be sure I checked `arg.object_id`  in every call and its... **the same**

also checked same calls between difference scenarios and results didn't change at all.

My question is: How does cucumber saves same string between different When/Then calls ?

Comment: This is not a rails or rails 4 question. you should remove those tags.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber steps are globally defined and it will reuse steps. When you call remove! on the args, you are altering the global step which is resulting on your second call happening with the altered args.

Put in a Before hook and a pry and you can insepct the state of things.

```
Before do |scenario|
  binding.pry
end

[3] pry(#<Object>)> scenario.steps
=> Cucumber::Ast::StepInvocation, 40034540, Cucumber::Ast::StepInvocation, 40034500
```